# How to replace types in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

say I have

```
type Person = {
  name: string
  hobbies: Array<string>
}
```

and then this: `const people: Array<Person> = [{name: "rich", age: 28}]`

how do I add age AND replace hobbies with say a different type (`Array<number>`) to keep it simple

I know I can use `omit` to get rid of a property or intersections to add a property but I'm struggling to work it out

Obviously this is wrong but I want something like that

```
type Hobbies = Array<number>
type NewPerson = Omit<Person, "hobbies"> & Hobbies & Age

const people: Array<NewPerson> = [{name: "rich", age: 28, hobbies: [1,2,3]}]
```

Comment: Why do you have `number` in `people` the second time you showed it but not the first?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oops typo! should be hobbies as an of number ha. will edit

Answer (score 2):

You neet to intersect with object types that have the extra properties you want to add

```
type Hobbies = { numbers: Array<number>}
type NewPerson = Omit<Person, "hobbies"> & Hobbies  & { age: number }

const people: Array<NewPerson> = [{name: "rich", age: 28, numbers: [1,2,3]}]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwLACgopUBDAWwgC4pFh4BLVAcwKIAtkAjT+iRagILx4JEAB5aDZgD4CAXwIFQkKAAkuPPphzEArmU4J+UISPGp9h+NIX5l0AHIQA7nCRptAeTL1gYtyioADRQAEQc3LyIodJQAGRqGlFECdhQJExUegYIULYEAMZotFCQyGAANlmmomJOrkZosVgA2tikFNShDAVsoSEZWQBMABwhFjlI1C0AjEFDQQDMALpyy0A)

Answer (score 2):

You're right you'd use `Omit` and an intersection. To remove `hobbies` and add `age` you'd do `Omit` and intersect with an *object type* defining `age` and the new version of `hobbies`:

```typescript
type Person = {
    name: string;
    hobbies: Array<string>;
};

type NewPerson = Omit<Person, "hobbies"> & { age: number, hobbies: number[] };

const people: Array<NewPerson> = [{ name: "rich", age: 28, hobbies: [1,2,3] }];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbn0IAtkAjLuiRKgEF48YiAA8NekwB8rAL6tcoSFAByEAO5wkaTFADypOsHE6UqADRQARJx59ENmVABkOKMUaUiAV1JcCNb2vPxUqP6B8ADaALpQiri4AMZoNFCQyGAANj7CohIa2ggWLljR2ERkPjb0yew21l4+AEwAHMHcoQJQ0QCMli2WAMzx8rGsQA)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the example below helps.

```
type NewPerson = Omit<Person, "hobbies"> & { hobbies: Array<number>, age: number }

const people: Array<NewPerson> = [{name: "rich", age: 28, hobbies: [1, 2, 3]}]
```

Use the Omit type to remove the hobbies property from the Person type and then add in the new hobbies and age properties.